# How would I convert this JSON stored in a database column into a table with columns and rows?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, parsing

Given the below JSON data and table that holds the data, how can I query the values and write to a new table with rows and columns split?

Basic table that contains the JSON:

```
CREATE TABLE BI.DataTable
(
    JsonDataText VARCHAR(MAX)
);
```

JSON data:

```
   {
       "datatable": {
          "data": [
             [
                "ZSFH",
                "99999",
                "2022-08-31",
                571106
             ],
             [
                "ZSFH",
                "99999",
                "2022-07-31",
                578530
             ],
             [
                "ZSFH",
                "99999",
                "2022-06-30",
                582233
             ],
             [
                "ZSFH",
                "99999",
                "2022-05-31",
                581718
             ]
          ]
       }
    }
```

When I use the JSON_VALUE function, I get a null for each column.

```
    SELECT 
      JSON_VALUE (JsonDataText, '$.data[0]') AS MetricCode,
      JSON_VALUE (JsonDataText, '$.data[1]') AS RegionID,
      JSON_VALUE (JsonDataText, '$.data[2]') AS ReportingPeriod,
      JSON_VALUE (JsonDataText, '$.data[3]') AS MetricValue
    FROM BI.DataTable
    WHERE ISJSON(JsonDataText) > 0
```

Comment: can you explain, why you have an array in an array and why your inner arrays are not in "MetricCode" : "ZSFH", resdisgning your json will make your life much eassier

Comment: This is the raw data that is retrieved from an API. I thought it was oddly formatted as well.

Comment: Does it work better if you use correct selectors? e.g.: `JSON_VALUE (JsonDataText, '$.datatable.data[0][3]') AS MetricValue`

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning - you're correct, my path definitions were incorrect and your expression does return data as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `OPENJSON()` with the appropriate columns definitions and an additioinal `APPLY` operator is a possible approach:

```
SELECT j.*
FROM DataTable d
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(d.JsonDataText, '$.datatable.data') WITH (
   MetricCode varchar(4) '$[0]',
   RegionID varchar(5) '$[1]',
   ReportingPeriod varchar(10) '$[2]',
   MetricValue int '$[3]'
) j
WHERE ISJSON(d.JsonDataText) = 1
```

Result:

| MetricCode | RegionID | ReportingPeriod | MetricValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ZSFH | 99999 | 2022-08-31 | 571106 |
| ZSFH | 99999 | 2022-07-31 | 578530 |
| ZSFH | 99999 | 2022-06-30 | 582233 |
| ZSFH | 99999 | 2022-05-31 | 581718 |

Note, that the reasons for the `NULL` values returned from your current statement are:

- `JSON_VALUE()` extracts a scalar value from a JSON string, but the `$.datatable.data` part of the stored JSON is a JSON array with JSON arrays as items, so in this situation you need to use `JSON_QUERY()`.
- The `$.data[0]` path expression is wrong.

The following example (using `JSON_QUERY()` and the correct path) extracts an item from the `$.datatable.data` JSON array:

```
SELECT 
   JSON_QUERY(JsonDataText, '$.datatable.data[0]') AS MetricCode,
   JSON_QUERY(JsonDataText, '$.datatable.data[1]') AS RegionID,
   JSON_QUERY(JsonDataText, '$.datatable.data[2]') AS ReportingPeriod,
   JSON_QUERY(JsonDataText, '$.datatable.data[3]') AS MetricValue
FROM DataTable
WHERE ISJSON(JsonDataText) > 0
```